# JQuery append object to an appended object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to append an object to an already appended object:

```
$("#object1").append('<div id="object2'>foo</div>;
$("#object2").append('<div id="object3'>bar</div>;
```

this does not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your quotes are off. Wrap your HTML string in single quotes:

```
$("#object1").append('<div id="object2">foo</div>');
$("#object2").append('<div id="object3">bar</div>');
```

Comment: sorry my fault, i edited the post. this is not the problem

Comment: @zoid: then please edit and correct your posted code; that's all have to work with and if it doesn't accurately convey your *actual code* then it's worthless and the question becomes unanswerable.

Comment: @zoidbergi - Your code is still missing the closing parenthesis.

Comment: This solution seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/zzccD/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#object1")
  .append(
    $("<div id='object2'>foo</div>")
       .append("<div id='object3'>bar</div>")
  );
```